# JSON unmarshalling using JAX-RS and MOXy

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, moxy

I'm implementing RESTFul web service using Jersey 2.22.1 with MOXY as Json Provider.

For example I have the following entity User:

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String email;
    private Address address;
    private List<Phone> phones;

    // getters & setters

}
```

and additional classes

```
public class Address {

    private String type;
    private String value;

    // getters & setters

}

public class Phone {

    private String type;
    private String value;

    // getters & setters

}
```

This is my JAX-RS resource implementation:

```
@POST
public Response create(User user) {
   // some logic
}
```

Now when I'm sending POST request containting following json data:

```
{
   "id":"qwe12",
   "email":"emailname@g-mail.com",
   "address":{
      "type":"1WHEN-Honorable",
      "value":"1WHEN-M"
   },
   "phones":[
      {
         "type":"HOME",
         "number":"034-2342-12-31"
      },
      {
         "type":"WORK",
         "number":"31-21-3211-32"
      }
   ]
}
```

it works perfectly, MOXY automatically maps this json to user object and it's fine

But I need to handle json with another level of nesting, like this:

```
{
   "user":{
      "id":"qwe12",
      "email":"emailname@g-mail.com",
      "address":{
         "type":"1WHEN-Honorable",
         "value":"1WHEN-M"
      },
      "phones":[
         {
            "type":"HOME",
            "number":"034-2342-12-31"
         },
         {
            "type":"WORK",
            "number":"31-21-3211-32"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

As you can see there is another key called user, and I know it's not a good json structure but it's a requirement and I have to accept it as it is. Now I need to be able to handle it. For now I can see only one solution.

I can add another one class wrapper aroung User and pass it to the create method.

So it would look this:

JAX-RS resource:

```
@POST
public Response create(UserWrapper user) {
   // some logic
}
```

And java class:

```
public class UserWrapper {

    private User user;

    // getters & setters

}
```

It's working solution but I don't really like it because I need to add one more additional class. Would like to here your suggestions how to keep my java classes as it is and be able to accept json with one more level of nesting (i mean this user key).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

May not be the answer you're looking for, but I recommend using Jackson instead of MOXy. It's a more mature JSON framework with more features, and just works better. There may be a way with MOXy, but here is the Jackson way

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- You need to remember to remove MOXy -->
```

In a [`ContextResolver`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson), configure the `ObjectMapper` to unwrap the root value

```
@Provider
public class MyObjectMapperProvider implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public MyObjectMapperProvider() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
            return defaultObjectMapper;
        }
    }

    private static ObjectMapper createDefaultMapper() {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

The value it will look for to deserialize will either be

1. The value in a `@JsonRootName` annotation, e.g. `@JsonRootName("user")` (on the class)
2. The value in a `@XmlRootElement` annotation, e.g. `@XmlRootElment(name="user")` (on the class)
3. If there is no annotation, then the name of the class, with the first letter lower cased.

Also not, unless you are using any MOXy specific features, making the switch to Jackson, you probably will not need to make any changes at all to your classes. Jackson also supports JAXB annotations (for the most part).

If you want the response to be wrapped, you can also use

```
mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
```